# Firebase Functions: How to use second database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I initialize my functions to use second database instead of the default one?
I use the following code, but noticed a slower response while accessing the database.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://newdatabaseurl"
});
var database = admin.database();
```

The following code responds slowly:

```
await database.ref("restRooms").once('value').then(async (snap) => {
     ///some code
});
```

Connecting to second database invokes the query slowly.

Comment: Can you clarify what "slowly" means here? Specifically: can you edit your question to show how you measured the performance, what results you got, and what you expected it to be (and based on what you have that expectation)?